# Service vs Class instances in angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm newbie to angular 2. I had started working over services in angular 2. 
I understood that we need to decorate the class with @Injectable() to make it as a service as like below.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
@Injectable()
export class MyFirstServiceClass{
  SayHelloToService(){
  alert('Service called');
  return 'Hello, welcome your service...';
  }
}
```

After that we are accessing it from the constructor of our component class as like below :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MyFirstServiceClass} from './FirstService.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  constructor(private  servtest : MyFirstServiceClass )
  {    
      this.title =  servtest.SayHelloToService();
  }
}
```

My template code :

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  {{title}}
  <button id='btn' (click)='servtest.SayHelloToService()'>Click Me ! 
</button>
</div>
```

I was able to see the result even on button click and on load of page as component creation completes so no problem.

But, I was able to access even directly without any kind of @injectable just by creating the instance of that class 'MyFirstServiceClass' as like below :

```
export class AppComponent {
title = 'app';
 servtest = new MyFirstServiceClass();
   func1(){
   this.title= this.servtest.SayHelloToService();
   } 
}
```

I'm not getting how they both are differ to each other.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-pattern

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `@Injectable()` decorator does not make a class a service. Any class can be a service. Whether or not it behaves like a service is defined by how you register it. If it is registered in the `provider` array of a module or component, it is a service.

```
  providers: [
    ProductService,
    ProductEditGuard,
    ProductParameterService
  ]
```

Adding the `@Injectable()` is only required to tell a service that it needs to inject *other* services. Like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    private productsUrl = 'api/products';
    private products: IProduct[];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    // ...
}
```

Trying the above code without the `@Injectable()` decorator generates a syntax error: `Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ProductService`

**NOTE**: It is consider "best practice" to add the `@Injectable()` decorator to every service so if later developers do inject a service into the service it won't generate an error.

Comment: Thanks @Deborahk . One point I didnt get is "it needs to inject other services".  In your demo statements, To the class "PRODUCTSERVICE" , what was the "other service" you injected ? Please clear this...

Comment: In the code above, I'm injecting `HttpClient` into the ProductService class. Hence the need for it to have the `@Injectable` decorator. If I was not injecting any other service into ProductService, I would not technically need the `@Injectable` decorator ... but as I said above it is recommended in either case.